# How to model method parameters in class diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a project where class `Foo` has a member function which takes class `FooParam` as a parameter.  Now I want to draw a [UML class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) representing the relationship between class `Foo` and `FooParam`.

From the options on the table, inheritance, implementation, aggregation and composition are automatically excluded. Thus, the options that are left are association and dependency, but to my eyes none of them fits quite right.

Given the options, how exactly do we model method parameters in class diagrams?

Comment: Not all items of a class diagram are expressed visually. The type of an operation parameter (`FooParam` in your example) can be expressed textually in a class diagram. If you are not happy with this, you can add a dependency arrow from the `Foo` class to the `FooParam` class.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gerd, you will not see a "link" or "relationship" between `Foo` and `FooParam` classes. I put below what you should see by default.

[image]

Of course, you can always add an explicit link (as a dependency for example) but it is, for me, duplication of the information...

[image]

The best is maybe to have a tool which would be able to compute this "link" or "relationship" and show it to you in some way.

Comment: (It Gerd, not Gred ;-) The dependency below is a bit off and should not come from inside the class frame.